# how to save state of fragment with a connection to my service

Tags: android, android-fragments, service, fragment, bind

In my activity I use three buttons at bottom to choose between fragments like this for example:

```
scenarioFragment = new ScenarioFragment();
android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, scenarioFragment, scenarioFragment.toString());
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("stack");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

so in `ScenarioFragment`, I bounded a connection to my service.and whenever I change between fragments a new fragment is created and I have to bind a new connection.
I want to save all fragments state and restore it as they choose.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to what you said, your Fragment have the same Activity as a parent.

Assuming this, you could create a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel.html) (**Component introduced as part of the Android Architecture Components)** for your activity and put whichever state you want in them.

Then, inside each of your Fragments you can get the ViewModel with the statement:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ViewModelClassName.class);
```

The key to this statement is to make sure you pass in the getActivity so that you can get the same ViewModel instance in all the Fragments as long as they are attached to the same parent. If you pass the Fragment instead of the Activity like this `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModelClassName.class);` you will have a new instance of the ViewModel tied to the scope of the Fragment that will be cleared if the Fragment is destroyed.

This is possible because the ViewModel class will be created using the scope of the Activity and it doesn't matter how many time you recreate your fragment you will be getting the same ViewModel instance with your state.

You can learn more about Android Architecture components [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html).
If you wish to understand a bit more about how the ViewModel works internally you can find out more on a post I wrote [here](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/viewmodels-under-the-hood-f8e286c4cc72).